# jquery ajax call synchronous for databases

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm creating a web site using ASP. NET with a large client side that takes care of many events for the site. On the client side via AJAX I update, delete and add to the database (in that order!).
My question is, because the order of the tasks is very important: first- update database, second- delete from database, third- add to database: 
Should I make the AJAX call synchronous? by changing "async" to false"?
or should I leave it as true by default?? which approach should I take?

Comment: No, leave it true, and don't send the 2nd request until the first completes. Never use synchronous ajax unless you're trying to do something during a click or submit event that will result in the page reloading.

Comment: If you have to do 3 specific database updates in a specific order, you should be doing all 3 within a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

U should do this by sending only one ajax call for all the operation you needed and make that ajax call async false.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it would be better to instead use `async: true` and chain your requests so that they happen one after the other.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'put',
    url: '/model/7256185',
    data: {name: 'Lucy'}
}).then(function () {
    return $.ajax({
        type:'delete',
        url: '/model/7256186'
    });
}).then(function () {
    return $.post('/model', {name: 'bob'});
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log("All Done!");
    console.log(result);
}, function () {
    console.log('An error has occurred!');
    console.log(arguments);
});
```

This ensures that the requests happen in order, and it doesn't cause your page to appear broken during the requests (which is what happens with a synchronous request.)

It also allows you to use a loading gif if you so wish. With synchronous requests, loading gifs won't spin.

Answer (score 0):

You DEFINITELY need to use transactions either at the business or at the data layer of your backend.

I usually prefer performing brief tasks (each entity with their own repositories) and keep the connection open for as little as possible in the Data Layer, then manage the transactional logic in the business layer using - for example - the [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

After this, it doesn't really matter whether you call the service/method in a sync or async fashion.